# How can I connect to an IIS site being served on my computer from my iPad?

Tags: iis, ip

Both devices are connected to the same WiFi network.

I have set IIS bindings to allow connections to my IP:
[image]

However, my computer's IP address is the same as my iPad's.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: "However, my computer's IP address is the same as my iPad's", from where did you get that? Your Wifi router's built-in DHCP never assigns the same IP address to more than one devices. You might get some ideas on how to troubleshoot from https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef

Comment: That link you sent actually really helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially when I posted this question, I was using an xfinitywifi hotspot and I assume that came with a whole host of problems. Full-disclosure, I did not figure out how to make it work in this scenario.

However when I moved to my own home wifi network, I was still having this problem.

I had to do two things, one of which, I know is not recommended, but it was really easy.

First, I had to enter my network and sharing center and set my connection as home connection instead of public which is what I previously had it at.

Second, which is not recommended, I turned off Windows firewall. I only do this when I need to access my site from another device for debugging. I turn it back on when I am done. For a more permanent setup I know it is recommended to just enable the port you need, but I could not figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

That's not your IP. Every time you use a laptop on a Wifi network, you'll be using the public IP address of whatever network you're on.

The IP address of "your" computer doesn't belong to your computer. It belongs to the network you're connected to. Your computer is just borrowing it for a while.

Try to [set a static IP address](https://pureinfotech.com/set-static-ip-address-windows-10/) for your computer and use another machine to send ping command to it. Then use iPad to connect.